# Out of space while bulding Linux kernel

Tags: linux, disk-space, linux-kernel, compile

I am trying to build Linux kernel. I am getting out of space after a while. I unpacked it in `/usr/src directory`. It seems I have plenty of space. Can you please let me know what can be done about it. How much space does it need to compile & build kernel.

I am using VirtualBox.

```
root@vinay-VirtualBox:/usr/src/linux-2.6.39.3# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             6.9G  3.2G  3.4G  49% /
none                  669M  640K  668M   1% /dev
none                  675M   24K  675M   1% /dev/shm
none                  675M   96K  675M   1% /var/run
none                  675M     0  675M   0% /var/lock
/dev/sr0               39M   39M     0 100% /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.0.10_72479
```

Comment: if you're running out of space, obviously it needs more than 3.4GB!

Comment: I can add additional virtual hard disk to box , but how do I integrate it with the old one. In virtaul box the disk size can only be changed at the starting, i dont want to go thr installing OS again.

looking for a shortcut.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Out of *disk* space or out of *memory* space (=RAM+SWAP)?

Comment: out of disk space

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: More than 3.4 GB? Not plausible.

Comment: can you make a separate virtual disk and mount it as /usr/src after copying the kernel tree onto it?

Comment: @user unknown: I am skeptical myself, but am limited to the OP's information.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx  i jjust did that
/dev/sdb              7.9G  146M  7.4G   2% /usr/src

its showwing as above now .. 

i did mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /usr/src..

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: A recent tarball on my disk: linux-source-2.6.32.tar.bz2, is 64M  in size. Extracted it will be bigger, and during compilation it will generate intermediate files, and the the final .ko-files - in /lib/modules I find files of about 90M. In total you might need 200M or 300M disk space, but not 3G.

Comment: @vinay: Please: Show your command - an exact copy, and the errormessage - an exact copy too.

Comment: I finally got it done, I added a virtual disk to it & mounted it to /usr/src  .

It took about 6.5 GB to compile & build Linux kernel 2.6.39.3 .

Comment: @vinay you should post that as an answer. Flag once you've done.

Comment: @user unknown: FYI, building Chromium (the browser) took me 15+ GiB... and the ZIP file containing the binaries is like 40 MiB.

Comment: @user Compiling source uses many small files. Storage efficiency is probably not good.

Comment: I didn't compile my kernel for years, but in former times, till about 2005, I did, and I did it on machines which had a total disk size of 2GB. I compiled the whole KDE. It took a whole night on a 233 Mhz machine, but I don't remember hard-disk problems. What is using so much disk-space suddenly? Yes, the kernel grew since 2005, but not that much!

Answer (score 1):

> I added a virtual disk to it & mounted it to /usr/src . It took about
>   6.5 GB to compile & build Linux kernel 2.6.39.3

-- ( [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/308877/out-of-space-while-bulding-kernel#comment-329303))

Answer (score 1):

Here are the statistics for a linux-3.19 compilation on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with no plus feature.

After I downloaded and decompressed it, without removing the compressed file, I had 2GB in use.

After the installation of gcc, make and after compilation (make and make modules), now I have 13GB in use.